# How do I add ngx_http_geoip2 to an AWS ARM EC2 Instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I have a working nginx server using an ARM EC2 instance. I tried to follow the steps [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/987783/how-to-add-ngx-http-geoip2-module-support-to-nginx) to add the module but when I try to run `sudo make install` the version doesn't update (currently trying to install 1.25 instead of the current 1.22

```
[... nginx-1.25.0]$ ./configure --add-dynamic-module=../ngx_http_geoip2_module-3.4   --with-http_ssl_module
[... nginx-1.25.0]$ make
[... nginx-1.25.0]$ sudo make install
[... nginx-1.25.0]$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.22.1
```

What am I missing?

```
Linux .....compute.internal 6.1.25-37.47.amzn2023.aarch64 #1 SMP Mon Apr 24 23:19:51 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I suggest you check the version in the build directory and the version deployed, I wonder if it's just not being installed into the path